# Remove specific column if exists in CSV file

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, csv

I've a CSV file that contains about 25 columns.
Some rows of the file contain 26 columns, so that I want to search for the lines that contain that extra column and remove it to be able to use awk with the whole file.

Fields are separated by **; Semicolon**. The extra column is in the format of **VARNAME="Text is here"** and the value "text is here" is arbitrary text.

I managed to remove the **VARNAME** from all lines but I can't explore a pattern that matches the arbitrary value (the quoted text).

My target is, find lines with that extra column (**VARNAME="Text is here"**) and remove it.

**Example:**

Current file:

```
ROW1: VAR1:"Value 1";VAR2="Value 2";VAR3="Value 3"
ROW2: VAR1:"Value 4";VAR2="Value 5";VAREXT="Different Values";VAR3="Value 6"
```

Target File should be:

```
ROW1: VAR1:"Value 1";VAR2="Value 2";VAR3="Value 3"
ROW2: VAR1:"Value 4";VAR2="Value 5";VAR3="Value 6"
```

Comment: you have wrote: "*to search for the lines that contain that extra column*". Post the exact search extra column value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
sed 's/;VAREXT.[^;]*//' file  #combine with -i for in-place editing
```

Testing:

```
a=$'"ROW2: VAR1:"Value 4";VAR2="Value 5";VAREXT="Different Values";VAR3="Value 6"'
b=$'"ROW2: VAR1:"Value 4";VAR2="Value 5";VAREXT="1234567";VAR3="Value 6"'
c=$'"ROW2: VAR1:"Value 4";VAR2="Value 5";VAREXT="VAREXT";VAR3="Value 6"'

echo "$a" |sed 's/;VAREXT.[^;]*//'
echo "$b" |sed 's/;VAREXT.[^;]*//'
echo "$c" |sed 's/;VAREXT.[^;]*//'

"ROW2: VAR1:"Value 4";VAR2="Value 5";VAR3="Value 6"
"ROW2: VAR1:"Value 4";VAR2="Value 5";VAR3="Value 6"
"ROW2: VAR1:"Value 4";VAR2="Value 5";VAR3="Value 6"
```

Comment: What if the VAREXT had a literal `;` inside the double quotes'

Comment: @RakeshSharma I suppose that will fail, as all solutions using ; as delimiter would fail too.

Comment: The dot in your  regular expression `;VAREXT.[^;]*` is redundant or meaningless in this pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

Expecting your csv has no header, there are no spaces after semicolon and only one `VAREXT...` per line, then with respect to your sample try:

```
sed 's/;VAREXT=\"[A-Za-z0-9 ]*\"//' in.csv
```

Where the value of **VAREXT** could be a composite of letters, digits and spaces.